# Using Coloris.js how to start with the picker open when page loads?

Tags: javascript, colors, picker

I am using the JavaScrip color picker [Coloris.js](https://coloris.js.org/). All the examples seem to have to click the color chip to open the color picker. My question is how can you start with it open when the page loads?

I tried what seemed like the accessibility option way to do it. However, It seemed not to do what I wanted.

I also tried the the inline option and it seems to do weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the CSS position of the desired container
// to "relative" or "absolute".
// Note: This should be a scrollable container with enough space to display the picker.

```js
Coloris({
  parent: '.container',
  inline: true,
)}
```

source : [https://coloris.js.org/](https://%20https://coloris.js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input type="text" class="coloris instance3" value="#ffcc00">
```

get the Coloris element

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("instance3");
```

open the color picker by code:

on page load execute a click event

```
elem.click()
```

[image]